# liblapacke: undefined reference to symbol 'dposv_'

Tags: makefile, cmake, linker

I am trying to compile this library: https://github.com/dthuerck/culip but I get the following error during make:

```
[ 73%] Linking CXX executable culip-tests-la
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/culip-tests-la.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++    -fPIC -fopenmp -march=native -m64 -DGPU_BLAS -Wfatal-errors -O3   CMakeFiles/culip-tests-la.dir/tests/la/test_sparse.cc.o CMakeFiles/culip-tests-la.dir/tests/la/test_spmv.cc.o CMakeFiles/culip-tests-la.dir/tests/la/test_sqmr.cc.o  -o culip-tests-la  -L/gcc/home/sahmad/Desktop/culip/dependencies/mmio/lib -rdynamic /usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64/libcudart_static.a -lpthread -ldl -lrt liblibutils.so liblibdatastructures.so liblibla.so liblibalgorithms.so -lmmio liblibtest.so -lblas -lhwloc -lgfortran -lblas -llapacke -lmmio ../dependencies/gtest/lib/libgtest.so ../dependencies/gtest/lib/libgtest_main.so /usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64/libcudart_static.a -lpthread -ldl -lrt /usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64/libcublas.so /usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64/libcusparse.so /usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64/libcusolver.so /usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64/libcudadevrt.a -lblas -lhwloc -lgfortran -llapacke ../dependencies/gtest/lib/libgtest.so ../dependencies/gtest/lib/libgtest_main.so /usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64/libcublas.so /usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64/libcusparse.so /usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64/libcusolver.so /usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64/libcudadevrt.a /usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64/libcudart_static.a -lpthread -ldl -lrt -Wl,-rpath,/gcc/home/sahmad/Desktop/culip/build:/gcc/home/sahmad/Desktop/culip/dependencies/mmio/lib:/gcc/home/sahmad/Desktop/culip/dependencies/gtest/lib:/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64 
/usr/bin/ld: /gcc/home/sahmad/Downloads/lapack-3.8.0/liblapacke.a(lapacke_dposv_work.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dposv_'
//usr/lib/libopenblas.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/culip-tests-la.dir/build.make:171: recipe for target 'culip-tests-la' failed
make[2]: *** [culip-tests-la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/gcc/home/sahmad/Desktop/culip/build'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/culip-tests-la.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/culip-tests-la.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/gcc/home/sahmad/Desktop/culip/build'
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I know this is a common error and I've tried following other's solutions on similar errors but as I have little experience with Ubuntu and C++, I couldn't solve it. It's obviously some kind of linking error and I tried linking the libraries in a different order, but no luck yet.

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04 with gcc 5.4.0 and CUDA 9.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Cielaah, could you link the solutions you tried so others can check them more easily and maybe help you build from them?

Comment: From the command line, the relative order of linking `blas` and `lapacke` libraries is:  `... -lblas -llapacke ... -lblas ... -lapacke`. According to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282486/can-linking-with-the-same-library-twice-be-a-problem-with-g), the second linking with `blas` is ignored (as it is **shared** library), so there is effectively no `blas` followed `lapacke` in the command line, and you get this classic "undefined reference" error.

Comment: If you want us to help you in fixing your code, you need to post **part of this code**, responsible for such linking order. The link to the repo isn't sufficient: it is off-site and quite large. Ideally, we want to have [mcve], which reproduces your problem, to be in the question post itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lapacke is an interface to lapack**: lapack is not embedded in lapacke. As a result, **both need to be linked.** Moreover, the order matters: all functions used in the library on the left must be defined by libraries on the right. 
As a consequence, **could you try to link `-llapacke -llapack -lblas -lm`?**

More specifically, at some point in the test, the function `dposv_` is called and this function is implemented in Lapack, not in Lapacke. Indeed, Lapacke contains an interface `LAPACKE_dposv()`, calling `LAPACKE_dposv_work()`, calling `LAPACK_dposv()`, that is `LAPACK_GLOBAL(dposv,DPOSV)`, boiling down to `dposv_` on your plateform.

In Cmake, if the lapack library is in your library search path, modifying the `target_link_libraries()` in the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/dthuerck/culip/blob/master/tests/la/CMakeLists.txt) could locally do the trick.

```
target_link_libraries(culip-tests-la lapacke lapack blas m)
```

The best way to go would be to add the following commands to the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/dthuerck/culip/blob/master/tests/la/CMakeLists.txt) to make sure that Blas and Lapack are installed and found:

```
find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)
find_package(LAPACK REQUIRED)
```

The last line sets flags like `LAPACK_LIBRARIES` and `LAPACK_LINKER_FLAGS` as defined in  [FindLAPACK.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindLAPACK.html) and  [FindLAPACK.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindLAPACK.cmake). Then (As in [CMake link atlas and llapack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614824/cmake-link-atlas-and-llapack)):

```
target_compile_options(culip-tests-la ${LAPACK_LINKER_FLAGS})
target_link_libraries(culip-tests-la lapacke ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES})
```

The line `find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)` is superfluous as it is almost the first thing done in  [FindLAPACK.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindLAPACK.cmake). Moreover the variable `${LAPACK_LIBRARIES}` likely contains something like `-llapack -lblas -lm` or more. It can be printed by:

```
message( ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES} )
```

Comment: Thank you for your great insight and thorough answer! Adding -llapack to the linking fixed the problem for me. I also removed the second -lblas without a problem.